# NextVal of postgresql usage

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE SEQUENCE :schema.empseq;

CREATE TABLE emp(empid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL(':schema.empseq'));
```

I am execute like  `psql  -d dbname -U username -f emp.sql -v schema=post`

Getting an error

> schema ":schema" does not exist

Comment: It looks like `:schema` is a placeholder of some sort you must replace with the actual name of your schema.

Comment: But the requirement is to pass the value of the schema.So i am passing a schema value using -v option

Comment: Did you try this with input redirection like I suggested yesterday? `psql -d db -U user -v schema=post < emp.sql` The problem is really that you're loading this from a script. I believe the struggle is expanding the parameter from within the script. I suggested almost the same thing as AKX yesterday and that is the correct way to expand that variable. With the unquoted `:` and concatenation.

Comment: You might be able to simplify this problem by writing a bash script to handle variables and calling the psql commands from there.

Comment: yes . I tried as you said but still i am facing same issue

Comment: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 6:       SELECT NEXTVAL(:'schema' || '.seqname')

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/devel/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-INTERPOLATION) talks about how `psql` interpolates values into SQL.

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE :schema.empseq;
CREATE TABLE emp(empid bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL(:'schema' || '.empseq'));
```

might work for you.

Comment: The tricky bit is he is not using the interactive console for running the commands, he's trying to expand the variable inside of a script.